# How to realistically mitigate miner heat

Tags: antminer

Does anyone have a system for flushing the heat generated by their miner out of their house/office w/o letting in outside temp. I'm worried about the cost of cooling a miner in the south in August. I previously heard that antminer s7/s9 miners can operate in the ~135 degree f range. Also, if this is off topic for the forum let me know.

Comment: It's called an air conditioner!  That's precisely what an air conditioner does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When people speak of electricity costs of mining, they are not just referring to the miner, itself.  They are also talking about the cost of cooling the miners.

Anyone who has worked in a datacenter knows that cooling is a major cost, if not the main cost.  This is why large scale datacenters are often built next to water sources; to cool the servers.  If you are running a miner, you need to keep the ambient temperature cool (air conditioning), and perhaps have heatsinks and water cooling systems on the miner, itself.

The cost of cooling a mining rig may make mining unprofitable, depending on the issue ambient temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I am mining from Africa, where temperature is a bit high. The daily average temperatures are around 30 degrees celcius.

This is what I did to control the heat.

I have ducts for the exhaust fans which directly takes the heat out.

But that wasn't enough, the outside temperature in my opinion was a bit too high, and if you factor in dust accumulation, I could see why the miners were showing higher temperature.

So I installed an air condition.

The air condition does two thing's,

1. Ensures filtered air is supplied
2. Ensures that the intake is actually cold air.

This had a huge impact on the stability of the machine's.

I attempted taking out the duct tubes which takes the heat out, but I realised, it meant my AC unit was overworking to cool the room.